# TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Estou tentando traduzir um codigo de Python 2.7 para 3.6

O codigo 2.7 funciona perfeitamente:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

values = """
   {
    "exchange_code": "PLNX",
    "exchange_market": "BTC/USDT"
   }
"""

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-API-KEY': 'xxxxxx',
'X-API-SECRET': 'yyyyyy'
}

request = Request('https://api.coinigy.com/api/v1/ticker', data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

O codigo para 3.6 :

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

values = """
   {
    "exchange_code": "PLNX",
    "exchange_market": "BTC/USDT"
   }
"""

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-API-KEY': 'xxxxxx',
'X-API-SECRET': 'yyyyyy'
}

request = Request('https://api.coinigy.com/api/v1/ticker', data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print(response_body)
```

Retorna o seguinte erro :

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 request = Request('https://api.coinigy.com/api/v1/markets', values, headers=headers)
>   ----> 2 response_body = urlopen(request)
>         3 print(response_body)
>
> C:\Users\Marcelo\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
>       221     else:
>       222         opener = _opener
>   --> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>       224 
>       225 def install_opener(opener):
>
> C:\Users\Marcelo\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
>       522         for processor in self.process_request.get(protocol, []):
>       523             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
>   --> 524             req = meth(req)
>       525 
>       526         response = self._open(req, data)
>
> C:\Users\Marcelo\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_request_(self, request)
>      1246                 msg = "POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, " \
>      1247                       "or a file object. It cannot be of type str."
>   -> 1248                 raise TypeError(msg)
>      1249             if not request.has_header('Content-type'):
>      1250                 request.add_unredirected_header(
>
> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Pelo que eu entendi eu tenho que passar os parametors para urllib.request no formato bytes e nao no formato str, mas nao sei qual a forma correta de converter os valores.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente esse código:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

values = """
   {
    "exchange_code": "PLNX",
    "exchange_market": "BTC/USDT"
   }
"""

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': 'xxxxx',
    'X-API-SECRET': 'yyyyyy'
}

request = Request('https://api.coinigy.com/api/v1/ticker', data=values.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print(response_body)
```

O problem aparentemente estava no jeito que você estava lidando com o dicionário. Era necessário codificar os valores antes.

Da documentação (inglês):

> For an HTTP POST request method, data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The urllib.parse.urlencode() function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns an ASCII string in this format. **It should be encoded to bytes before being used as the data parameter**.

Tradução do trecho destacado:

> O parâmetro deve ser convertido para bytes antes de ser usado como
>   parâmetro da variável data.

Comment: poderia traduzir esse trecho destacado em ingles?

Comment: @diegofm pronto. Melhor?

Comment: A msg de erro não aparece mais no entanto a resposata da chamada é :

b'{"err_num":"1057-32-01","err_msg":"Missing or empty parameters:"}'

Comment: @RiskTech Acabei de testar no Python 3.6.0 e obtive essa resposta: b'{"data":[{"exchange":"PLNX","market":"USDT\\/BTC","last_trade":"1115.0200000000","high_trade":"1123.4000000000","low_trade":"1026.1450002000","current_volume":"8157.2646000000","timestamp":"201
7-03-21 20:23:53","ask":"1115.9999999900","bid":"1115.0100000000"}],"notifications":[]}' 
Pode testar novamente?

Comment: Funcionou realmente, pode ser que o feed estava derrubado quando testei. Muito obrigado